# Windows Server: Multiple reserved ip's delete

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, netsh

As far as I know using the command:

```
netsh dhcp Server serverIP Scope  x.x.x.x delete reservedip reservationip macaddress[..]
```

Will delete a single reserved ip, is it also possibile to delete a whole range (through netsh)? I could not find a syntax which deals with this problem. The OS is Windows Server 2008.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother using netsh to delete the reservation range; use a loop to delete them one by one.

```
for /L %x in (2,1,254) do echo netsh dhcp Server serverIP Scope  192.168.1.%x delete reservedip reservationip macaddress[..]
```

The `/L` is a literal and does need to be written in exactly. The `%x` can be replaced with `%y` if desired. You can even nest:

```
for /L %y in (0,1,255) do for /L %x in (2,254,1) do netsh dhcp Server serverIP Scope  192.168.%y.%x delete reservedip reservationip macaddress[..]
```